# Start app with default color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicolor

The menuView must have the default color for everyone. But anyone from application settings with RGB sliders can change the color of the menuView.
So I want to set the default color with yellow, and set the slider to change color menuView. And after the color change, that can be save.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIViewX!

  var redval = Float()
  var greenval = Float()
  var blueval = Float()


  @IBOutlet weak var NewMessage: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var Camera: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var NewPost: UIButton!

  var tableData: [Model] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    self.menuView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(redval), green: CGFloat(greenval), blue: CGFloat(blueval), alpha: 0.45)
  }
 }
```

With the string

```
self.menuView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(redval), green: 
CGFloat(greenval), blue: CGFloat(blueval), alpha: 0.45)
```

I can change color by slider RGB with app, but now I want impost the default color first that this can be change.

Code slider for change color

```
import UIKit

 class ViewSettings: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var redslider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet var greenslider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet var blueslider: UISlider!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func change(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChangeColor", sender: self)
}

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ChangeColor" {
        let destanitaion = segue.destination as! ViewController
        destanitaion.redval = redslider.value
        destanitaion.blueval = blueslider.value
        destanitaion.greenval = greenslider.value
    }
}


}
```

Comment: A straightforward way to do it is to save each red, green, blue value as a `Double` in `UserDefaults`. Then extract each component and reconstruct the `UIColor`. You can make a `UserDefaults` extension to make this cleaner as well.

Comment: can you give me an example? the color i want impost default is #colorLiteral(red: 0.9966391622, green: 1, blue: 0.2095825737, alpha: 0.7946946448) /* #f2f0f0 */  @Paolo

Comment: UP @Paolo view the update

Answer (score 2):

Store each color component as a `Double` in `UserDefaults`:

```
// when saving

defaults.set(redVal, forKey: "defaultColorRedValue")
defaults.set(greenVal, forKey: "defaultColorGreenValue")
defaults.set(blueVal, forKey: "defaultColorBlueValue")
```

To extract each value:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    redVal = CGFloat(defaults.double(forKey: "defaultColorRedValue"))
    greenVal = CGFloat(defaults.double(forKey: "defaultColorGreenValue"))
    blueVal = CGFloat(defaults.double(forKey: "defaultColorBlueValue"))

    self.menuView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: redval, green: greenval, blue: blueval, alpha: 0.45)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

-User user default for set RGB default after app kill,

on your slider value change store RGB

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(redval, forKey: “Red”)
defaults.set(greenval, forKey: “green”)
defaults.set(blueval, forKey: “blue”)
```

On view did load get value from user default

```
let red = defaults.float(forKey: "Red")
let green = defaults.float(forKey: "green")
let blue = defaults.float(forKey: "blue")

 self.menuView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red), green:CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: 0.45)
```